# WPF - Trigger to change Foreground and Background of multiple Button's object

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, storyboard, eventtrigger

I am trying to do a **RoutedEvent** to activate **ColorAnimation** over a `TextBlock` and a `Panel` inside `Buttons`. My goal is to change the TextBlock's Foreground and the Panel's Background when using the **MouseEnter** and **MouseLeave** RoutedEvents.

The below code is actually working. But it works only when the mouse cursor is over one of these two objects (which makes sense).

I can't figure what should I do to activate both **ColorAnimations** when the mouse is over the **Button** (specially if it is not over the `Panel` or the `TextBlock`)

> Here is an example of how the button looks like normal:
>
> [image: Normal]
>
> This is how the button looks like when I focus the `Panel`:
>
> [image: MouseEnter - Panel]
>
> This is how the `Button` looks like when I focus himself (the Button background has the same color as the Panel's Background and the TextBlock's Foreground)
>
> [image: MouseEnter - Button]
>
> And this is how the button should looks like when the mouse is over the button
>
> [image: OK]

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="Path" TargetType="Path">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Name="btnTest" 
        BorderThickness="0"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        Margin="5,5,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    <StackPanel>
        <Path Style="{StaticResource Path}" Fill="Gray"
                Stretch="Fill" Width="98.851" Height="94.776"
                Data="M819.2,0H204.8C92,0,0,92.2,0,204.8v614.4C0,931.8,92,1024,204.8,1024h614.4c112.6,0,204.8-92.2,204.8-204.8V204.8  C1024,92.2,931.8,0,819.2,0z M879,337.8l-15.8,93L774.6,463.6L702,403.4l15.8-93.2l88.4-33L879,337.8z M786.2,594.8  c-61.601,22.8-129,7-180-35.399L217.8,831.2L128,702.8L528,423c-16.8-95.2,28.6-188.4,112.8-219.6c56.2-20.8,117.2-9.6,166.2,25  l-136,50.4L646.6,424L760,518l136-50.4C881.2,525.6,842.4,574,786.2,594.8z"
                />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock}" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        TEST
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

**EDIT 1**
I tested Ahmad's code, and it worked partially. When my cursor is over the `Button`, the **DataTrigger** works. But when I leave it (IsMouseOver = false) the `Path` **Fill** and the `TextBlock` **Foreground** are not changing back:
**OBS:** I had to add **DataTrigger.EnterActions** to avoid the following error message:

> A value of type 'BeginStoryBoard' cannot be added to a collection or
>   dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection'.

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Path" TargetType="Path">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ahmad initial code, I did some research and I found the **EnterActions** and **ExitActions** properties. With a single **DataTrigger**, I can define my animations when the `IsMouseOver` is **True**

```xml
<Style x:Key="Path" TargetType="Path">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of EventTrigger add a DataTrigger which binds to the Text/Panel UI elements ancestor

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
    <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
              <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
         </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger>

other triggers for IsMouseOver being false ...
```

You do this for both the Panel or the TextBlock and simply remove the trigger from the button and when the mouse is above the Button it will trigger and the text/panel storyboard.

Comment: Hello Ahmad!
Thank you for your answer

Comment: I edited my post to share the code results with Ahmad's suggestion, but it did not work as I expected.